# ¿Como sacar un caracter de un string dentro de un arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola tengo un ejercicio que me pide introducir 5 palabras, que las ordene (Con el collections.sort) y que luego borrarán las palabras que contengan la letra M (mayuscula o minúscula).

¿Alguien sabe como se puede sacar?
Porque lo que intento

es que saque el Arraylist.get(i), pero no existe un contains o algo similar

Osea si yo tengo un string en el arraylist que sea "mama" o "maMa", como hago para que lo descarte? Es que no encuentro en ningun sitio como hacerlo

He probado con una solución que daban en google que era hacer un boleano y un arraylist.contains, pero aun así no funciona, me he quedado asi:

Main:

```
package listas;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import utilidades.Entrada;

public class P04_listas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String n;
        
        ArrayList<Palabras> lista = new ArrayList<Palabras>();
         boolean ans = lista.contains('m');
         boolean ans2 = lista.contains('M');
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Palabra ");
            n=Entrada.cadena();
            lista.add(new Palabras(n));
        }

        
        Collections.sort(lista);
        for (Palabras palabras : lista) {
            System.out.println(palabras);
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            if (lista.get(i).equals(ans) ) {
                lista.remove(i);
            }
            System.out.println(lista);
        }
        
    }

}
```

La clase entrada no hace falta que la ponga, es solo para recoger información

Clase palabras:

```
package listas;

public class Palabras implements Comparable<Palabras>{

    String palabra;

    public Palabras(String palabra) {
        super();
        this.palabra = palabra;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Palabras [palabra=" + palabra + "]";
    }

    public String getPalabra() {
        return palabra;
    }

    public void setPalabra(String palabra) {
        this.palabra = palabra;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Palabras o) {
        if (o.getPalabra().length()>palabra.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else if (o.getPalabra().length()<palabra.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
        return 0;
        }
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Gracias por leerme

Answer (score 0):

[`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) sí tiene una función [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-). Solo que no te sirve porque todos los caracteres de algún elemento debe coincidir.

Lo que puedes hacer en este caso es recorrer el arreglo y usar el [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) o [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) de la clase [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
   
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("Palabra ");
        String n = Entrada.cadena();
        lista.add(n);
    }

    ...

    // Quita las palabras que tienen m después del primer caracter
    ArrayList<String> palabrasAQuitar = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String palabra : lista){
        if (palabra.indexOf("m", 1) > 0) {
            palabrasAQuitar.add(palabra);
        }
    }

    lista.removeAll(palabrasAQuitar);
}
```

Decidí reemplazar tu clase `Palabras` por `String` para simplificar el código.

Alternativamente, puedes quitar las palabras que cumplan una condición con [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-). Un ejemplo con la misma condición de antes:

```
lista.removeIf(palabra -> palabra.indexOf("m", 1) > 0);
```